# I cannot import pyplot from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Error:

```
  from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2362, in <module>
    install_repl_displayhook()
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 126, in install_repl_displayhook
    ip.enable_gui(ipython_gui_name)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3378, in enable_gui
    raise NotImplementedError('Implement enable_gui in a subclass')
NotImplementedError: Implement enable_gui in a subclass
```

Comment: @han, `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` should work as well.....

Comment: Ah. I see the issue.  The shell is rendered in a Qt QPlainTextEdit, which does not support inline graphics. Did you fire up `IPython` from `cmd` ?

Comment: I don't have any experience with `ipython`. Could you try `ipython notebook` instead of `ipython` and report back ?

Comment: I can run it in Jupyter notebook, but cannot run it in Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues just getting a plot to appear using pandas and getting the same error.  This solved it for me.  Had to downgrade ipython. Now plots appear from command prompt / PowerShell.

```
pip uninstall ipython 
pip install ipython==7.24.1
```

Another workaround was to define the backend manually for matplotlib:

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

Although setting specifically backend is apparently frowned upon. For some reason just running below query also seems to work:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['backend']
```

This allowed use of newer ipython versions (tested with `8.17.2`)